# Count permutation with duplicates and restriction

Tags: arrays, math, permutation, combinatorics

I want to count the permutations with duplicates and only `3` different signs `0,1,2` and the restriction that no `0` follows directly after a `1`.

Example:

Valid: `01202212`

Invalid: `10...`

I though the count of these subset of permutations
is `(3^count(0))*(2^count(1))*(3^count(2))` but this is wrong. If not how can i compute the exakt count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear that:
-valid sequence of length K ending with 1 might be composed
adding 1 to any valid sequence of length K-1

-valid sequence of length K ending with 2 might be composed
adding 2 to any valid sequence of length K-1

-valid sequence of length K ending with 0 might be composed
adding 0 to valid sequences of length K-1 ending with 0 or 2

So simple Python program

```
def valid123(n):
    a = [[0]*3 for _ in range(n)]
    a[0][0] = 1
    a[0][1] = 1
    a[0][2] = 1
    summ = 3
    for i in range(1, n):
        a[i][0] = summ - a[i-1][1]
        a[i][1] = summ
        a[i][2] = summ
        summ = sum(a[i])
    return summ

for i in range(1,10):
    print(i, valid123(i))
```

gives

```
1 3
2 8
3 21
4 55
5 144
6 377
7 987
8 2584
9 6765
```

Corresponding [OEIS sequence](http://oeis.org/A001906) has simple recurrent representation `a(n) = 3*a(n-1) - a(n-2)` - subset of Fibonacci, and some closed formula does exist:

```
a(n) = (ap^n - am^n)/(ap-am), with ap := (3+sqrt(5))/2, am := (3-sqrt(5))/2
```

Comment: Its possible to build a rank mand unrank function? Optimally with parameters ```c0,c1,c2``` for the count of ```0,1,2```? How to do this?

Comment: I think this is rather difficult (if at all possible)